# Angular 1.5.7 - $http POST request being cancelled by browser

Tags: angularjs, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm running into an issue where for some reason, an $http post to my api server is being cancelled at the browser level, which is errantly triggering my error handler logic. I'm tailing the server logs, and I can verify that the server is in fact getting the request and returning a 200 status code - everything is fine on that end.

It would seem that something is causing the request to cancel *mid-request*! Setting breakpoints (using Chrome's web inspector) in the Angular source code for `xhr.abort` are never hit, although trying this out in Safari leads to the same behaviour.

I'm only able to see provisional headers in chrome, where the request is marked as cancelled. In Safari the request continues to *"spin"* as if it were still active (while breaking inside the error handler).

I can post my code here, but it's pretty vanilla, and I'm not convinced the problem is here:

#### Initiator

```
Service.validate(token, email)
.then(function(response){
  if (!response.data.is_valid) {
    // Do a thing
  }
}).catch(function(err){
  // Do a thing
});
```

#### User Methods

```
Service.validate = function(token, email) {
  return $http.post(configs.apiUrl + '/validate', {
    email: email,
    token: token
  });
};
```

Please let me know if there is any other info I can provide that might shed some more light on the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I actually just built an api front-end in Angular, and the only way I got $http to work from a service was by returning a promise.

```
Service.validate = function(token, email) {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            $http
                .post(configs.apiUrl + '/validate', {
                    email: email,
                    token: token
                })
                .then(
                    function success(response) {
                        resolve(response.data);
                    },
                    function error(err) {
                        reject(err);
                    });
        });
}
```

Then in controller the code should be the same.

This also seems to follow [ES6](http://es6-features.org/#PromiseUsage) standards.

Comment: I was under the impression that returning `$http()` _was_ the same as returning a promise? I'm using this pattern across my codebase, and this is kinda the only place it doesn't seem to work. I'm hesitant to refactor my entire $http/promise structure project-wide...can someone verify this? Either via documentation or otherwise?

Comment: I thought returning $http was the same as well, weird that it's the only place it didn't work. In that case I'd also like to get some verification on this...